# Stretch fixed to bottom parent div to div child's width

Tags: html, css

So, I have a main container that shows like the following:

[image]

I want to be able to adapt the parent div to the number of child's it receives. Let's say we remove div2. The result should be something like this:

[image]

Instead, the parent div does not stretch to the width of the div child's

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="main-container">
    <!-- Card container -->
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">div1</div>
      <div class="card">div2</div>
      <div class="card">div3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer container -->
    <div class="footer">i am a footer</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #B3B3B3;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  text-align:center;
}
.card-container {
  color: #3B3D3D;
  height:105px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #0095D3;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.card {
  width:100px;
  float:left;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried the **display: inline-block;** solutions out there but since the parent div must be fixed to the bottom, I am not seeing the desired result.

Any help will be precious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/n3ptun3/pen/PPgWNb

You don't need to use `display: inline-block`.

I've left your HTML alone, and simplified some of your CSS: `.card-container` and `.footer` don't need `float: left;` and `width: 100%;`. They are both block-level elements so they will take up 100% of the width, and they don't need anything to wrap around them.

On the `.main-container`, you can't set `margin: 0 auto;` and `position: fixed;`. `position: fixed;` removes the ability for centering via margin. `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` were stretching the size of the main container, so those need to be removed. `width: 100%;` and `max-width: 400px;` were trying to fix the width issue, but that wouldn't allow resizing based on content.

Instead you need to set `left: 50%;` (places left edge of element at 50% of the parent's width, i.e. the viewport width, in this case) and then `transform: translate(-50%);` to bring the element back toward the left by 50% of its width. Thus bringing the element to the center of the window/viewport.

Now, if you remove one of the "cards," it will resize the "main-container," while keeping everything fixed to the bottom and centered.

```
.main-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #B3B3B3;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-container {
  color: #3B3D3D;
  height: 105px;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #0095D3;
  height: 45px;
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on your new information (re: the increased width or added "cards"), I've found that the issue lies with the left position on the `.main-container`. When you position the element by 50% and its width is more than 50% of the parent, it runs into the right side of the parent div, and you get the stacking. To fix this, you can instead remove the `float: left;` on `.card` and add `display: flex;` on `.card-container`. This will allow you to increase the width of the "cards" while keeping them from stacking.

I've updated the code here: http://codepen.io/n3ptun3/pen/PPgWNb

```
.main-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #B3B3B3;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-container {
  color: #3B3D3D;
  height: 105px;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  //  float: left;
}

.footer {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #0095D3;
  height: 45px;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the code neptune, as Nenad's code, this does what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, as i was trying your code again, I noticed that if my cards width goes above 171px I can't have the same effect, since they start to stack below each others. The same goes for @nenad-vracar code.

Comment: Try the new code I added using flexbox instead of floats.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neptune, that does the job exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/136/

You can try to remove one `.card` on click and see what hapens here https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/138/

**CSS**

```
.main-container {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #B3B3B3;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.footer {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #0095D3;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
}
.card {
  width:100px;
  height:105px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="card">div1</div>
    <div class="card">div2</div>
    <div class="card">div3</div>
    <div class="footer">i am a footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does exactly what I need, thanks very much Nenad